# How to get one value from struct of array in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I want to get the value that is inside of struct in Solidity,
but I have no idea how to get it.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;
contract PlaceList {

    struct hoge {
    uint id;
    address user;
  }

  hoge[] public hoges;

  constructor() public {
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

  function set(uint id) public {
    hoges.push(hoge(id, msg.sender));
  } 

  function getId() public view returns(uint) {
    return (hoges[0].id);
  } 
}
```

When I call `getId`, console command say this,

```
ƒ () {
              if (abiItemModel.isOfType('constructor')) {
                return target.executeMethod(abiItemModel, arguments, 'contract-deployment');
              }

              return targe…
```

Could you give me any advise how to get `id` by using solidity function, please?

Comment: Show us the code how you call `getId`

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin I call by this code `this.state.list.methods.getID().call`
`list` has contract information.

Answer (score 0):

hoges[0][0] will work as it points to the first element, 'id' .